# Column 'fRecurrence' does not belong to table Calendar eror loading Default.aspx

Tags: 2007, error, calendar

I am currently working an issue where an unhandled exception occurs when loading the dafault.aspx.   This error is pointing me to an issue to a calendar web part or LVWP that is added to the default aspx.  The issue is that I am not aware of how I can go ahead and get around the error so I can access the page to see what might be occuring and begin troubleshooting.   Is this something I might be able to do with Designer to at least see what the culprit might be?   As I am more involved with front end development I have limited access to get to the infrastructure to look at code etc.

Any assistance in troubleshooting would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point is to check out log files from ULS trace log in

```
c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\logs
```

Also check the event viewers application log for errors.

If you are on a development server you can enable debugging, stack trace and disable custom errors page (details [here](http://blogs.technet.com/stefan_gossner/archive/2006/12/19/how-to-enable-debugging-in-wss-3-0.aspx)).

Another debugging option is to use [SPTraceView](http://hristopavlov.wordpress.com/2008/06/19/sptraceview-lightweight-tool-for-monitoring-the-sharepoint-diagnostic-logging-in-real-time/) to get trace logs "as they happen".

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) is also useful for tracking down what happens between server and client.

Comment: Anders,

Thank you for the advice.  The good news is that the user was just starting out with creating a calendar and there was no content or at least it wasn't important to her.  I ended up deleting the LVWP and the offending calendar off site using SharePoint Designer.  This in turn ghosted the default.aspx bu found this the easier approach.